# How do I add part of a bigger tensor with smaller tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working in keras and I want to add two tensors but the shape of the first one is (1,28,28,1) and the second one is (1,4,4,1). now I want to add the 4x4 upper part of the first tensor with the second one. how can I do it? in the following code, I want to add wtm with encoded. if they had the sam size, I used lambda layer and do this, but now, I do not know. could you please help me? I appreciate any help.

```
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
#conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e', kernel_initializer='Orthogonal',bias_initializer='glorot_uniform')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
#DrO1=Dropout(0.25,name='Dro1')(BN)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can again use a `Lambda` layer but this time you need to pad the small tensor with zeros to match the shapes. For that you can use:

```
keras.backend.spatial_2d_padding(x, padding=((0, 28-4), (0, 28-4)), data_format=None)
```

which will pad the 2nd and 3rd dimensions of a tensor. Have a look at the [backend documentation](https://keras.io/backend/). Overall it will be something like:

```
Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + K.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((0, 24), (0, 24)))
```

You can pad different ways to add to the different regions of the bigger tensor.

Comment: Thank you very much. but I want to be sure I used the correct code. I use it wpad=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + K.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((1, 23), (1, 23))))
encoded_merged=wpad([encoded,wtm]) right?

Comment: when I used 24 instead of 23 the output shape was (1,29,29,1) so I changed your code to 23

Comment: I forgot an `1`, if you want top left corner you need `(0, 24)` which means no padding on the left and 24 on the right.

Comment: I appreciate your help. and If I want to put it in other places I just need to change these values. right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You move up down, left right by adding zeros basically.